# How can I parse a .docx file containing images with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docx

I have a .docx file. It contains lots of images as well as text. I want to parse the data along with image and convert it into HTML. How can I do this? I tried docx gem, but it only reads the text part and skips the image.

Comment: you can try Docsplit with it has a function to `render` images `Docsplit.extract_images('example.doc', :size => '1000x', :format => [:png, :jpg])`

Comment: Go through this for documentation https://documentcloud.github.io/docsplit/

Comment: It extracts images and text separately. But different images are associated to different text in my file. Can you suggest anything that parses the file sequentially?